# Hacer un permutador en php

Tags: php, javascript

He encontrado el siguiente permutador codificado en **Javascript:**

```
<script>
    var letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    letras = letras.split("");
    numLetras = letras.length;
    permuta = new Array;
    combina = 2; //nº de letras a combinar;
    serie = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < combina; i++)
        serie *= numLetras;
    for (i = 0; i < serie; i++)
        permuta[i] = '';
    subSerie = serie / numLetras;
    for (i = 0; i < combina; i++) {
        per = 1;
        let = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < serie; j++) {
            permuta[j] += letras[let];
            per += 1;
            if (per > subSerie) {
                per = 1;
                let += 1;
                if (let > numLetras - 1) let = 0;
            }
        }
        subSerie /= numLetras;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < serie; i++)
        document.write(permuta[i] + '<br/>');
</script>
```

Lo que hace es mostrarme todas las **combinaciones posibles** de una cadena con una longitud determinada en la variable *combina*, lo que quisiera es pasarlo a **PHP** lenguaje php y lo llevo algo así:

```
<?php
    $letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $letras = explode($letras,"");
    $numLetras = strlen($letras);
    $permuta = array();
    $combina = 2; #nº de letras a combinar;
    $serie = 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $combina; $i++)
        $serie *= $numLetras;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $serie; $i++)
        $permuta[$i] = '';
    $subSerie = $serie / $numLetras;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $combina; $i++) {
        $per = 1;
        $let = 0;
        for ($j = 0; $j < $serie; $j++) {
            $permuta[$j] += $letras[$let];
            $per += 1;
            if ($per > $subSerie) {
                $per = 1;
                $let += 1;
                if ($let > $numLetras - 1) $let = 0;
            }
        }
        $subSerie /= $numLetras;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $serie; $i++)
        echo $permuta[$i].'<br/>';

?>
```

Pero me da un error muy consultado pora acá:  ***strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given*** pero no logro solucionarlo. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código que tienes esta bien salvo por unas cuantas cosas.

1) intentas hacer explode($letras) para obtener un array de los caracteres, pero $letras es un string por lo que puedes acceder de la misma manera, por lo que no hace falta usar explode. Ejemplo $letra[0] nos devuelve 'a'

2) $permuta[$j] += $letras[$let]; en php se concatena con "."
$permuta[$j] .= $letras[$let];

```
$letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$numLetras = strlen($letras);
$permuta = array();
$combina = 2; #nº de letras a combinar;
$serie = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < $combina; $i++)
    $serie *= $numLetras;
for ($i = 0; $i < $serie; $i++)
    $permuta[$i] = '';
$subSerie = $serie / $numLetras;
for ($i = 0; $i < $combina; $i++) {
    $per = 1;
    $let = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < $serie; $j++) {
        $permuta[$j] .= $letras[$let];
        $per += 1;
        if ($per > $subSerie) {
            $per = 1;
            $let += 1;
            if ($let > $numLetras - 1) $let = 0;
        }
    }
    $subSerie /= $numLetras;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $serie; $i++)
    echo $permuta[$i].'<br/>';
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: No me percaté de esa concatenación cuando pasaba el codigo a php, ya funciona de 10 @lDanny7

Answer (score 0):

El error te lo dice `strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`, 
a `strlen()` le estás pasando como primer parametro un `array` cuando espera un `string`.

```
// en esta línea convertís el string en array 
//reemplazas el explode por str_split
$letras = str_split($letras);
//deberías usar un count()
$numLetras = count($letras);
```

Comment: No me arroja lo que debería, solo me muestra un 0.

Comment: está mal el explode también, deberías usar una expresión regular como segundo parámetro o `str_split($letras);`

Comment: Bien, pero ahora me muestra con ceros (0) la cantidad de veces que se permutaria la cadena.